# How does valuePaidTo work?

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, transaction, decentralized-applications, plutustx

How does valuePaidTo work ? Does it give the value paid by the script to the pubkeyhash or is it the total value of the pubkeyhash for the pending transactions ?
Consider the following TxOut

```
txOutputs = [ 
   TxOut {
       txOutAddress = Address {
           addressCredential = PubKeyCredential "80a4f45b56b88d1139da23bc4c3c75ec6d32943c087f250b86193ca7",
            addressStakingCredential = Nothing
        },
        txOutValue = Value (Map [
                (,Map [("",87950820)])
            ]), 
        txOutDatumHash = Nothing
    },
    TxOut {
        txOutAddress = Address {
            addressCredential =
                ScriptCredential "d909e024ee4ed177cee1ec2b93de9afcf1ca1cb082f3af67ffa6a6e0",
            addressStakingCredential = Nothing
        },
        txOutValue = Value (Map [(,Map [("",2000000)]),
            (64636464636161,Map [("T1",1)])]),
        txOutDatumHash = Just 5b3b53a06a4c34209a6278e9c89b570e9bf76e1e040cd528a7f1bf4ce3535742
    }, 
    TxOut {
        txOutAddress = Address {
            addressCredential = PubKeyCredential "80a4f45b56b88d1139da23bc4c3c75ec6d32943c087f250b86193ca7",
            addressStakingCredential = Nothing
        },
        txOutValue = Value (Map [(,Map [("",20000000)])]),
        txOutDatumHash = Nothing
    }
],
```

In this case the script is paying `20_000_000` to the pubkeyhash `80a4f45b56b88d1139da23bc4c3c75ec6d32943c087f250b86193ca7`

Will `valuePaidTo` output `20_000_000` or `107_950_820` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perhaps the [source code](https://playground.plutus.iohkdev.io/doc/haddock/plutus-ledger-api/html/src/Plutus.V1.Ledger.Contexts.html#pubKeyOutputsAt) will explain it better than me.

in any case I'll try to explain it here.

`valuePaidTo` is defined as:

```
{-# INLINABLE valuePaidTo #-}
-- | Get the total value paid to a public key address by a pending transaction.
valuePaidTo :: TxInfo -> PubKeyHash -> Value
valuePaidTo ptx pkh = mconcat (pubKeyOutputsAt pkh ptx)
```

the comment

```
-- | Get the total value paid to a public key address by a pending
```

should already give you answer

in any case, we see that in the definition of `valuePaidTo` the function `pubKeyOutputsAt` is used

that function is defined in [the same source file](https://playground.plutus.iohkdev.io/doc/haddock/plutus-ledger-api/html/src/Plutus.V1.Ledger.Contexts.html#pubKeyOutputsA) just some lines above

in any case only having a look at the type signature should tell us a lot:

```
pubKeyOutputsAt :: PubKeyHash -> TxInfo -> [Value]
```

from this, we know that `pubKeyOutputsAt` returns a list of `Value` (`[Value]`), which we can assume (and confirm by reading the source) that are all the `Value`s going to the `PublicKeyHash`

and from Haskell we know that `mconcat` (used in `valuePaidTo`) is something like the following

```
mconcat :: Monoid a => [a] -> a
```

where `Monoid` are "things with a binary operation that returns something of the same type", and `Value`s happen to be a valid instance of `Monoid` where the operation acts as a "sum"

so what `valuePaidTo` is doing is

1. take **all** the values going to the given `PublicKeyHash`
2. "sum" them

in your case then the output lovelaces value would be `107950820`